# Get a value from within an array of object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new no laravel. I know that it is a pretty basic question. But, I still can't figure it out. Heres my Array output and I want to get the value of name from within this array. This is the output I get in postman after I used print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [name] => Test 2322              
            [id] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want all of them

```
foreach ($datas as $datavals) {
       echo $datavals['name'];
}
```

If you want 0 array name element value Just call following :

```
   echo $memus[0]['name'];
```

Comment: use second one @SoumyaRauth

Comment: The loop one worked fine. But, the 0 index solution didn't. And I have only one index.

Comment: Oh it did work perfect. My bad... You are great bro.. :)

Comment: Cool.. @SoumyaRauth if my ans is help for you.. click accept answer button

Answer (score 7):

In case this is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) you can use the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) method

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('name');

$plucked->all();
// ['Desk', 'Chair']
```

If in your case you do not have a collection you can create it with the **collect** method.

In your case:

```
$myarray = collect($initialArray); //You can ignore this if it is already an array

$nameArray = $myarray->pluck('name')->all();

foreach($nameArray as $name)
{
    echo $name; //Test 2322
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array with `foreach` on blade and get `index="name"` for each entry like this:

In View

```
@foreach($data as $d)

   {{$d['name']}}

@endforeach
```

In Controller

```
foreach($data as $d){

   // This is the value you want
   $name = $d['name']

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In newest version of laravel you can use the [Arr::pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pluck) helper function to take an array of all names values.

In your case

> Arr::pluck($array, 'name')

Will output

> ['Test 2322']

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply write the array name with the indices and key which have to access.Suppose $a[] is array then $a[0]['name'] and the value at zero index of array will be retrieved or you can parse it in loop which will give the value of key ['name'] at every indices. 
foreach($a as $item)
{
  print_r($item['name']);
}
```